# Appending Text And Value When Creating newOption() with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Something very strange is happening and after trying so many other options I dont know what to do. I'm trying to create a HTML option with Javascript. I'm able to get the option to be created however no text nor value is being appended. If anyone has a different approach I'd like to see. Thanks.

JS

```
function createOption{
var text = 'Orange';
var value = 'Fruit'
var additionalData = '#fruit123';
var pages = document.getElementById('pages');
var pageContainer = document.getElementById('pageContainer');
pages.style.display = 'block';
pageContainer.style.display = 'block';

document.getElementById("pages").insertBefore(new Option('', ''),
document.getElementById("pages").firstChild);

pages= new Option(text,value).dataset['id'] =additionalData;
}
```

HTML

```
 <button type="button"onclick="createOption();return false;">

<div id="pageContainer" style="display:none;">

<select id="pages" style="display:none; cursor:pointer;" onchange="getOption();">
<option>Please make a choice</option>
</select>


<div id="page_link"></div>
</div>
```

This is the output I see :
[image]

Comment: @davidbuzatto: Where am I styling?

Comment: @Rounin: yes I'm appending, text, value and data-id

Comment: @BalloonFight sorry, it true. You just want to append adition data.

Comment: @BalloonFight Please see the edits I made to my answer, they should do the trick for you if you use the code I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text('Your text here')
option.value('your value here')


document.getElementById('pages').add(option);
```

First, we create our option HTML element, then add the desired text, as well as the value, and after that is done we are taking our option and adding it to the HTML select element via the `.add()` method.

Alternatley, if you just wanted to use the Option class, you could do so like this:

```
var option = new Option("Text", "Value")

document.getElementById('pages').add(option)
```

As a result, your code would look like this:

```
function createOption{

     var text = 'Orange';
     var value = 'Fruit'
     var additionalData = '#fruit123';
     var pages = document.getElementById('pages');
     var pageContainer = document.getElementById('pageContainer');
     pages.style.display = 'block';
     pageContainer.style.display = 'block';

     //Create the option
     var option = new Option(text, value);
     pages.add(option);

     //create the data-id attribute, add it to the option
     var attribute = document.createAttribute("data-id");
     option.setAttributeNode(attribute);

     //Assign the respective data to the data-id attribute
     option.dataset['id'] = additionalData;

}
```

Take special note of `.setAttributeNode()`.  This is a built in JavaScript method that allows us to assign an HTML element an attribute that has been created from within our code.  I noticed that you did not add the `data-id` attribute to your HTML, so in case there was a reason, we have assigned the attribute dynamically.

Let me know if it works!  I've tested it and it should do the trick for you.

Comment: I like this but where is dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var select = document.getElementById( "mySelect" );

select.add( createOption( "a", "1", { add1: "foo1", add2: "bar1" } ) );
select.add( createOption( "b", "2", { add1: "foo2", add2: "bar2" } ) );
select.add( createOption( "c", "3", { add1: "fruit", add2: "loop" } ) );
select.add( createOption( "d", "4" ) );
select.add( createOption( "e", "5", { add1: "none", add2: "john doe" } ) );

select.onchange = function(evt) {
 
    var allData = "";
    var option = evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex];
    
    allData += option.innerHTML;
    allData += " value: " + option.value;
    for ( d in option.dataset ) {
     allData += "\n    " + d + ": " + option.dataset[d];
    }
    
    alert( allData );
    
};

function createOption( text, value, data ) {

 var newOpt = document.createElement( "option" );
    newOpt.innerHTML = text;
    newOpt.value = value
    
    for ( d in data ) {
        newOpt.dataset[d] = data[d];
    }
    
    return newOpt;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Make a choice!</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

```
var pages = document.getElementById('pages');

// new Option([the text to show], [the value of option], [boolean, defaultSelected], [boolean, selected or not]);
var opt = new Option('The first text', 'the value', true, true);

// pages.add([the Option object], position);
pages.add(opt, 0);
```

---

The HTML result of `new Option('The first text', 'the value', true, true);`
is:

```
<option value="the value" selected>The first text</option>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/xv9Ld74e/)